# Regular expressions: how to match numbers?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to use regular expressions to match numbers like these:

```
58158
60360
98198
```

That is in the format `ABCAB`.

I use code below to match `ABAB`:

```
(([\d]){1,}([\d]){1,})\1{1,}
```

such as `5858` but how to match ABCAB(58158)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For numbers in the format `ABCAB`:

```
(\d)(\d)\d\1\2
```

This places no restriction on `A=B=C`. Use [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `A!=B!=C`:

```
(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)\d\1\2
```

**Edit:**

There is no boundary matching so `58158` will be matched in `36958158`:

```
$num=36958158;
preg_match('/(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)\d\1\2/',$num,$match);
echo ">>> ".$match[0];

>>> 58158
```

Comment: @jlee why do you want to use regex for that? Just split and compare fragments in the normal way you'd do it using your language's standard library.

Comment: @jlee formatting and some explanation goes along way. Can `A=B=C` here?

Comment: no, they are three different digit, but AB appears 2 times, and c between them.

Comment: @sudo_O You can do it with lookaheads:  /(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)\d\1\2/   http://regexr.com?3436s

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan nice one, good to think in both directions.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan The above code works! but if the number is not only 5 digits, how to match? e.g. 36958158, 36581589, find ABCAB from it.

Comment: @jlee, do you mean find if 36958158 is ABCAB?  or find a substring of five characters which is of the form ABCAB?  Or find the longest substring which is ABCAB?  Or some other combination?

Answer (score 0):

To match integers in the form ABCAB, use `\b(\d\d)\d(\1)\b`.

`\b` is a word boundary and `\1` references the first group.

Example (in JavaScript so that it can be tested in the browser but it works in most regex solutions) :

```
var matches = '58158 22223 60360 98198 12345'.match(/\b(\d\d)\d(\1)\b/g);
```

gives

```
["58158", "60360", "98198"]
```