# Regex match number in ABAB (must identical)

Tags: php, regex

i've search many answer to match `ABAB pattern` that match arbitrary character sort of 1212 or 2323, have read [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346178/regular-expressions-how-to-match-numbers)
 but i found that the pattern to match ABAB pattern not work, it also match `4444`

i try to figure out the pattern to match such subject below:

```
2323
4545
9898
```

but may not match 4444 or 5555 because that is not in **ABAB** pattern, i name it **AAAA** pattern
can someone give me clue
thanks

Comment: You need a back reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: does it have to match both ABAB and AAAA or ABAB ONLY?

Comment: should only match ABAB not AAAA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(\d)(?!\1)(\d)\1\2
```

- `(\d)` - capture the first digit to group `$1`.
- `(?!\1)` - check that the second digit is not the first digit.
- `(\d)` - capture the second digit to group `$2`.
- `\1` - match the third digit if it is the same as the first.
- `\2` - match the fourth digit if it is the same as the second.

Working example: http://www.regex101.com/r/aV2uG1

This is a relatively confusing regular expression, and the task can be easily solved by a few lines of code. I'm not big on PHP, but this seems to work:

```
$s = '1112';
$valid = (strlen($s) === 4) && ($s[0] === $s[2]) && ($s[1] === $s[3]) &&
         ($s[0] !== $s[1]);
```

Comment: You could also explain how the pattern operates!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - I answer quick and then expand - hope that's OK `:)`

Comment: @Kobi, your answer work fine, thanks, but can you add one more pattern match ABBA

Comment: @xnome, this should do: `(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(\1\2|\2\1)`... [DEMO - regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yP6rE9)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and more general regex pattern you can use for the ABAB pattern is

`(.+)(.+)\1\2`

**Breakdown:**

`(.+)` - Match one or more characters and store in capture group  `1`

`(.+)` - Match one or more characters and store in capture group  `2`

`\1` - Match same item in capture group `1`

`\2` - Match same item in capture group `2`

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/qJ2wM7/1